# Track the last two focus Textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a certain number of Textboxes, I need to track the last two focused Texboxes. This is the approch that I attempted.

```
private Control _focusedControl;
private Control _lastfocusedControl;

private void PCp1txt_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _lastEnteredControl = (Control)sender;
}
private void PCp1txt_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _lastEnteredControl = (Control)sender;
}

private void PCp2txt_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _focusedControl = (Control)sender;
}

private void PCp2txt_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _focusedControl = (Control)sender;
}
```

This is not working because when I press the button the contenent of the _lastfocusedControl will be the same as _focusedControl because another control was focused by clicking that button.

Comment: You don't need to handle `LostFocus`.

Comment: Don't post answer as part of the question. If none of the posted answer are helpful and you still want to post your own answer, post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `Enter` event of all those `TextBox` controls using a single handler and in the handler and keep track of last `n` focused `TextBox` controls:

```
const int n = 2;
TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[n];
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var destination = new TextBox[n];
    Array.Copy(textBoxes, 1, destination, 0, textBoxes.Length - 1);
    textBoxes = destination;
    textBoxes[textBoxes.Length - 1] = (TextBox)sender;
}
```

In above example, we are shifting the array to left, then assign the sender to the last element. This way the array always contains the last n focused `TextBox` controls for you.

Comment: What I was looking for was TextBox_Leave event which behaves differently than LostFocus event, one is called just once, the other is called everytime you actually lose the focus. I solved my problem by using the two methods already existing in the property page, Leave and enter. Thank you for the answer tho.

Comment: There is no difference between Leave and LostFocus in this context. You need to rely on `Leave` or `Enter` event. Above code perfectly keeps track of last n focused TextBox controls.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, to make it simpple, do something like when your textbox get focused, put the name of it into an array, for example, and after that,  list the last two name added of the array created.

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't need the text but I need the actual control because I need to switch them like TextBox1 = TextBox2